# What functions can be used to call information about files?

Tags: r

I need to get information on the extent, resolution, and cell number of the my file. I'm working with raster files.

Comment: https://www.neonscience.org/raster-data-r

Comment: @Joanne Sims Could you please reword your question. When asking about R is helpful to give information on the possible packages you are using or even version numbers.  Does the command `str( object )` provide useful information?

Comment: I am using library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(tidyverse) When I use #@class I get CRS but when I try #@resolution get the Error: no slot of name "resolution" for this object of class "CRS". I pull in a file for my hw and I projected it

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
library(raster)
# r <- raster("filename")
r <- raster()
extent(r)
ncell(r)
res(r)
```

You can read more about the methods in the raster package [here](https://rspatial.org/raster/pkg/index.html)